# Where does the notation $\mathrm{Ad}(U)$ for $a\mapsto UaU^*$ come from?

Tags: notation, operator-theory

I have often seen, in the context of operator theory and operator algebras, the notation $\mathrm{Ad}(U)a=UaU^*$, where $U$ is a unitary operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and $a$ is a bounded linear operator on $H$.  I have no idea what "Ad" stands for, where/how this notation came into common use, nor whether it fits into a more general context (e.g., for similarities or other automorphisms outside of the context of operator theory).  Some Google searching revealed a [use of "$\mathrm{Ad}$" in the theory of Lie groups](http://books.google.com/books?id=kQ4P8STBKHQC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false) that doesn't quite match with the above, but might have a common origin.

> Where does "$\mathrm{Ad}$" come from, especially in the context of $\mathrm{Ad}(U)a=UaU^*$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation_of_a_Lie_group

Comment: I'm pretty sure that @Qiaochu's right. I'd even go so far as to say that the motivation stems from the finite-dimensional case $A = M_{n}\mathbb{C}$, where the unitary group $U(n) = \mathcal{U}(A)$ leaves the subspace of self-adjoint matrices (= its Lie algebra) invariant.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said anti-self-adjoint ($a^{\ast} = - a$) before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in the comments:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation_of_a_Lie_group –  [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan) [Apr 23 '11 at 18:27](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/where-does-the-notation-mathrmadu-for-a-mapsto-uau-come-from#comment75127_34754)
>
> I'm pretty sure that @Qiaochu's right. I'd even go so far as to say that the motivation stems from the finite-dimensional case $A=M_n(\mathbb C)$, where the unitary group $U(n)=\mathcal U(A)$ leaves the subspace of anti-self-adjoint matrices (= its Lie algebra) invariant. –  [t.b.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5363/t-b) [Apr 23 '11 at 18:47](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/where-does-the-notation-mathrmadu-for-a-mapsto-uau-come-from#comment75145_34754)